# Apple Push Connector Mule Studio Extension

Tags: apple-push-notifications, mule

I'm trying to get the connector to send Apple Push Messaging. 
My first attempt was installed using "install software" Mule Studio (Linux). Seems everything was fine but the icon does not in the stream canvas.So I can not add to the flow.

Then I tried to add it as a global variable, did not work either. In the project properties I changed the version of the ESB runtime.
Mule Server 3.4.0 EE
Mule Server 3.4.0 EE
Mule Server 3.4.0 CE
Mule Server 3.4.1 EE
Mule Server 3.4.2 EE
Cloud Mule Runtime (Dec 2013)

I tried a second path, I myself build the connector.
I downloaded the project and built with DevKit 3.4.3 as directed by
http://mulesoft.github.io/apple-push-connector/guide/install.html

It was hard work to build the project zip finally my POM file stay like this....

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<parent>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-devkit-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-module-apple-push</artifactId>
<packaging>mule-module</packaging>
<name>Mule Apple Push Connector</name>
<version>3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<description>Mule Cloud connector to Apple Push Notifications</description>
<url>http://www.github.com/mulesoft/apple-push-connector</url>

<properties>
    <devkit.studio.package.skip>false</devkit.studio.package.skip>
    <licensePath>LICENSE.md</licensePath>
    <category>Standard</category>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.notnoop.apns</groupId>
        <artifactId>apns</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apple-push</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
    <name>MuleSoft Repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
    <name>MuleSoft Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>


</repositories>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com:mulesoft/apple-push-connector.git
    </connection>
    <developerConnection>
        scm:git:git@github.com:mulesoft/apple-push-connector.git
    </developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/mulesoft/apple-push-connector</url>
</scm>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <excludeMuleDependencies>false</excludeMuleDependencies>
            <inclusions>
                <inclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mule-module-apple-push</artifactId>
                </inclusion>
            </inclusions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
```

Installed my new zip from target, with the same results. Connectors that do not appear in my Apple Push connectors.

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who can provide some information.

Regards

Comment: By "Installed my new zip from target" do you mean installed the plug-in in Studio from the ZIP *update site* generated by DevKit?

Comment: Yes,
mvn clean package -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false 
built a updatesite.zip in / target. Then I import from "install software" adding a new local site.

Thank You for answering.

Comment: Then I don't understand why it doesn't show in Studio :'(

Comment: Do not know either. I follow these steps and I can not see it.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_9-Tyk-yUQ

Comment: just test version 3.0 but same thing happens
https://github.com/mulesoft/apple-push-connector/releases

Comment: I confirm it doesn't work: I've built the 3.0 tag and installed it via the UpdateSite.zip, and nothing shows in Studio 3.5. Seems broken to me: let's follow this https://github.com/mulesoft/apple-push-connector/issues/3

Comment: Ok, thanks David. I opened the issue (tcolepc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MuleSoft said, you need manually fix the connector until they fix it themselves by changing:

```
@Module(name = "apple-push", schemaVersion = "3.3")
public class ApplePushCloudConnector
```

to:

```
@Module(name = "apple-push", schemaVersion = "3.3", friendlyName="Apple Push")
public class ApplePushCloudConnector
```

Comment: Indeed, the icon appears in the palette. Regards. Best Regards.